# Using setTimeOut for ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to write an chat application using ajax. So I need to check users messages table in database every 100 millisecond(0.1 second). Is any problem if i use setTimeOut to call ajax for every 100 millisecond? Any performance issue? Any pitfall or anything?

Comment: no any problem but just make sure your ajax and backend is capable of sending response back within or less than 90milisecond...

Comment: how i can make sure about that?

Comment: use firebug firefox add on that will show you response time and content...also use yslow firefox addon for see which cause response delay...

Comment: I use your solution in one scenario as it needs to be Internet Explorer compliant, but just becasue of that.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15633965/744859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very bad idea. While it might work on your local machine and a few users, it can't scale to more users easily. I suggest you to look at websockets and long polling.

Comment: You are suggesting long-polling so can you suggest any example for that..? As per i know long-polling can be achieve using setTimeout...right.?

Comment: @DipeshParmar The difference between long polling and regular polling is that you prevent your requests from timing out, and the server responds when it wants to. You only make a new request when the previous one expires or completes. You wouldn't necessarily be using setTimeout, since when you send the next request depends on how long the server takes to respond.

Comment: @DipeshParmar sending multiple requests is just frequent multiple requests at short intervals, not long polling. Long polling essentially means the server will not write any response and hold the request till it has any data to write (or till the request times out, which can be a longer time out than a few seconds). The client makes new requests only if the current request expires or if the current request gets a response with data.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi which approach are you talking about? The thing which you described in your question is not a good idea, like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative would be to use `Socket.IO`. It makes this task a lot easier

Socket.IO makes it cross browser solution

example from [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

**Server:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Client (browser):**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

For PHP, [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) class will be a good fit and for client side [jquery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/)

Comment: It's a good suggestion, and I am a node.js developer myself, but the question is tagged asp.net and php. Does asp.net have any websocket-like solution?

Comment: @Munim IIS7 doesn't support it, but IIS8 will. I believe web sockets in PHP are currently possible.

Comment: I am asp.net developer. How i can use this in asp.net??

Comment: I am not sure if this will be the most appropriate solution, but try using [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript knows two sorts of timers: setInterval and setTimeOut. setInterval just fires every 100 miliseconds, setTimeOut scedules the next call 100 miliseconds after the previous. You should keep this behaviour in mind while tuning your app. You also may consider webworkers, who really do their job on a separate thread. They communicate message-based which sounds a suitable solution for your problem. The exact delay (100 miliseconds or more) is something you really need to try out. The book of John Resig shows that the smalles practical timer delay differs a lot across browsers, from 21ms (IE9) to 1ms (Opera).